# firestore cloud functions needs 150-200ms - normal?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i have a short cloud functions which should do the job in 3-4ms, but it needs up to 150-250ms.
Is this normal or is there any error in code?

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const db = admin.firestore();

export const deleteTestDoc = functions.firestore
  .document('test-docs/{docId}')
  .onDelete(async (snapshot) => {
    const deletedData = snapshot.data();
    console.log('deletedDoc' + deletedData);
    const docId = deletedData.id;
    const docTime = deletedData.time;
    const counterRef = db.collection(`test-docs/`).doc('user-counter');
    try {
      await counterRef.update({
        deleted: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        docTime: docTime,
      });
      console.log(
        'Transaction success! Increment field deleted for id: ' + docId
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code performs multiple an asynchronous operation, updating a document in Firestore. The Cloud Function won't complete until this asynchronous operation completes, and 150-200ms sounds quite reasonable for such a database operation.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal for some invocations to take longer than you'd expect. In serverless environments, this is called a "cold start".  You haven't provided enough information to know how exactly you're observing your code executing over time, or any sort of specific performance observations, but I suggest you do a web search for "cloud functions cold start" to learn more about the issue and what can be done to minimize the problem (cold starts can't be eliminated, as is the nature of all serverless compute products).  Firestore triggers in particular have always high a somewhat high latency, which is due to aspects of the system that you can't control.